# Customizing User Permission to specific "field" value

Tags: custom-list, item-level-permissions

I have created a very simple list (staff lists) that lets user create/edit their own input items, but not other users item.  However, I wanted to provide permission to person (or group of person) to edit/delete lists items within a specific field value (category).  For example, I have column field called "Staff Category" and contains four selection "International", "Local", "Contractor" and "Casual"...How can I provide permission to "Person A" to view/edit/delete all lists items that has a value of "Contractor" in the column "Staff Category"...and "Person B" to "International"...so on.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think there is any OOB solution for it. but using customization you can achieve it.

Comment: You could save the items in different Lists - List A is for Contractor items, List B is for International items.  Then managing the security/permissions is simple, don't give Person A access to List B, likewise Person B would have no access to List A.